# MatLab Применение функции eval

Tags: циклы, matlab, eval

Здравствуйте! Помогите разобраться. Я хочу этот код преобразовать в цикл.

```
r0=sum(e0')';
r1=sum(e1')';
r2=sum(e2')';
.......
r19=sum(e19')';
```

Мой вариант

```
matr300=ones(9,300); 
ya=20;
k=fix(size(matr300,2)/ya); 
for i=0:(ya-1)
    eval(['e' int2str(i) '=matr300(1:end, (i*k+1) : ((i+1)*k))']);
end 
for i=0:(ya-1)
    eval(['r',int2str(i),'=(sum(''e',str2double(i), '))']);
end
```

Это код с ошибкой в строке `eval(['r',int2str(i),'=(sum(''e',str2double(i), '))']);`. Конкретно не понятно как вызвать переменную e0, e1, e2.